# How often do Rainbow Puddings drop?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy-4

I am playing *Final Fantasy IV* on iOS and trying to obtain the `Rainbow Pudding` for the Namingway quest by farming Yellow Jellies in the Antlion Den.

I gather that the drop rate for the pudding should be around 0.4%, though I am not sure if that is per group of four (as the jellies appear) or per jelly.

In any case I have killed close to 2000 jellies and no pudding yet. I have also, I note, killed over 400 Admantoise but have never seen one drop a tent (its rare drop).

Is the lack of Rainbow Pudding drops an issue with *FF4* on iOS, a feature I am unaware of, or is this just a bit of bad luck?

Comment: I thought the pink ones dropped that (the super rare ones in the last dungeon) not the common ones elsewhere... http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Flan_Princess_(Final_Fantasy_IV)

Comment: You may want to read up on [the Gambler's Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz thx; contra [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). Note .04^2000 is 1.32x10^-2796. If that math for probability of a repeated event is correct (96% of failure repeated 2000x), it is more likely that your entire family will be eaten by wolves in the next hour than a rainbow pudding to not have dropped over 2000 repeated events! ;)

Comment: If you have the Treasure Hunter augment (from completing 100% of all dungeon maps), it doubles the drop rate. You get it before the final dungeon boss.

Comment: I think the odds of repeated outcome of non-rainbow pudding is 0.996 ^ 2000 ~= 0.00033 (3.3%) over 2000 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

The rainbow pudding is EXTREMELY rare (1% drop rate I think, 2% on queen flans) so it's just a bad luck streak :P